# How to write regex to enforce maximum of 255 characters?

Tags: regex

What regular expression would match any characters (including spaces), but have a maximum of 255 characters?  Is this it?

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9._]{1,255}$
```

Comment: Is it absolutely required that you use regex for this? In almost every programming language, there's an easier way to check the length of a string.

Comment: I need it to ensure that folks do not enter a string that is longer than the field in the db, else that sql insert would fail. I'm in Coldfusion and I'm not sure of anyother way of doing it other than regex & I do not want to use java script, for certain browsers e.g. mobile do not support javascript.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, *anything* would be:

```
^.{1,255}$
```

`.` doesn't allow new lines. If that's a problem, you can use the dot-all flag (usually `/s`).

If you want to add spaces to your regex, try this (note the space):

- `^[a-zA-Z0-9._ \t]{1,255}$` - Allow spaces and tabs.
- `^[a-zA-Z0-9._\s]{1,255}$` - Allow all whitespaces.
- `^[\s\w.]{1,255}$` - Same as the above (unless your flavor supports Unicode).

Answer (score 3):

Well that would not allow anything, if you want anything, you're better off using `^.{1,255}$`.

Or, if you want to allow nothing as well: `^.{0,255}$`